# Escape Quote in C# for javascript consumption

Tags: c#, escaping

I have a ASP.Net web handler that returns results of a query in JSON format

```
public static String dt2JSON(DataTable dt)
{
    String s = "{\"rows\":[";
    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            s += "{";
            for (int i = 0; i < dr.Table.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                s += "\"" + dr.Table.Columns[i].ToString() + "\":\"" + dr[i].ToString() + "\",";
            }
            s = s.Remove(s.Length - 1, 1);
            s += "},";
        }
        s = s.Remove(s.Length - 1, 1);
    }
    s += "]}";
    return s;
}
```

The problem is that sometimes the data returned has quotes in it and I would need to javascript-escape these so that it can be properly created into a js object.  I need a way to find quotes in my data (quotes aren't there every time) and place a "/" character in front of them.

Example response text (wrong):

```
{"rows":[{"id":"ABC123","length":"5""},
{"id":"DEF456","length":"1.35""},
{"id":"HIJ789","length":"36.25""}]}
```

I would need to escape the " so my response should be:

```
{"rows":[{"id":"ABC123","length":"5\""},
{"id":"DEF456","length":"1.35\""},
{"id":"HIJ789","length":"36.25\""}]}
```

Also, I'm pretty new to C# (coding in general really) so if something else in my code looks silly let me know.

Answer (score 174):

For .net 4.0 + there is standard
`HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode`

For earlier west wind solution described by Lone Coder is quite nice

Comment: I was working on software using Uri.EscapeDataString which caused problems when quotes were in the string. Changing to HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode was the right solution. They covert the characters differently. EscapeDataString -> %25, JavaScriptStringEncode -> \\".... Update. In the end I needed both i.e. Url.EscapeDataString(HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(str)) to get an api to accept quotation marks (") and the percentage character. There may be a better way, but hopefully this comment will help someone.

Comment: just wht i needed rite now

Comment: It converts " ' & < >" to "\u0027\u0026\u003c\u003e"

Comment: Yup - the encoding method is terrific.

Answer (score 36):

Here is an efficient and robust method that I found at http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/114530.aspx

```
/// <summary>
/// Encodes a string to be represented as a string literal. The format
/// is essentially a JSON string.
/// 
/// The string returned includes outer quotes 
/// Example Output: "Hello \"Rick\"!\r\nRock on"
/// </summary>
/// <param name="s"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static string EncodeJsString(string s)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append("\"");
    foreach (char c in s)
    {
        switch (c)
        {
            case '\"':
                sb.Append("\\\"");
                break;
            case '\\':
                sb.Append("\\\\");
                break;
            case '\b':
                sb.Append("\\b");
                break;
            case '\f':
                sb.Append("\\f");
                break;
            case '\n':
                sb.Append("\\n");
                break;
            case '\r':
                sb.Append("\\r");
                break;
            case '\t':
                sb.Append("\\t");
                break;
            default:
                int i = (int)c;
                if (i < 32 || i > 127)
                {
                    sb.AppendFormat("\\u{0:X04}", i);
                }
                else
                {
                    sb.Append(c);
                }
                break;
        }
    }
    sb.Append("\"");

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Using a method like this is important to avoid possible XSS attacks that could happen when JSON is eval'ed.

Comment: Nice. I did add an additional case statement to encode single quotes as well.

Comment: I don't think single quotes need to be encoded within double quotes.

Comment: Here is a Linq adaptation of this answer if you want: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59864990/1248177

Answer (score 11):

I think you should rather look at the JavaScriptSerializer class. It's a lot more stable, and will correctly handle any kind of data or escape characters etc. Also, your code will look a lot cleaner.

In your case your class can look like this:

```
public static String dt2JSON(DataTable dt) {
    var rows = new List<Object>();
    foreach(DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        var rowData = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        foreach(DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
            rowData[col.ColumnName] = row[col];
        rows.Add(rowData);
    }
    var js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    return js.Serialize(new { rows = rows });
}
```

This method will return a correctly serialized json string... For example, sth like this:

```
{"rows":[{"id":1,"name":"hello"},{"id":2,"name":"bye"}]}
```

Have fun! :)

Answer (score 5):

To correctly escape a string literal for Javascript, you first escape all backslash characters, then you escape the quotation marks (or apostrophes if you use them as string delimiters).

So, what you need is:

```
value.Replace("\\","\\\\").Replace("\"","\\\"")
```

What else jumps out to me is that you are using string concatenation in a loop. This is bad, as it scales very poorly. The += operator does not add characters at the end of the existing string (as strings are immutable and can never be changed), instead it copies the string and the added characters to a new string. As you copy more and more data each time, eEvery additional row roughly doubles the execution time of the method. Use a StringBuilder to build the string instead.

Use the `ColumnName` property to get the name of a column rather than the `ToString` method. The `ToString` method returns the `Expression` property value if it's set, only if that is not set does it return the `ColumnName` property.

```
public static String dt2JSON(DataTable dt) {
   StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder("{\"rows\":[");
   bool firstLine = true;
   foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows) {
      if (firstLine) {
         firstLine = false;
      } else {
         s.Append(',');
      }
      s.Append('{');
      for (int i = 0; i < dr.Table.Columns.Count; i++) {
         if (i > 0) {
            s.Append(',');
         }
         string name = dt.Columns[i].ColumnName;
         string value = dr[i].ToString();
         s.Append('"')
            .Append(name.Replace("\\","\\\\").Replace("\"","\\\""))
            .Append("\":\"")
            .Append(value.Replace("\\","\\\\").Replace("\"","\\\""))
            .Append('"');
      }
      s.Append("}");
   }
   s.Append("]}");
   return s.ToString();
}
```

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG: You don't decode it, you parse it. The purpose of escaping is so that the code can be parsed correctly. Once the data is parsed, the strings are back to their original form.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just do this:

```
string correctResponseText = wrongResponseText.Replace("\"", "\\\"");
```

Comment: Doesn't handle data with other special JS chars: backslash, newline, carriage return.

Comment: Not really so nicely done - as David mentioned, this won't work for many other special chars. @Lone Coder's answer below is better.

Comment: If the string being used in JS comes from a user, this approach is dangerous. It leaves you open to, for example `"</script>`, where if the string was being written out to a page script, would close the string and script tag followed by whatever the injector wanted to do.

Answer (score 0):

```
string.Replace(<mystring>, @"\"", @"\\"");
```

Comment: Doesn't work: `CS1056 Unexpected character '\'` and `CS1003 Syntax error, ',' expected`

Answer (score 0):

Works when i need send string from C# to html tag.

```
<buton onlick="alert('<< here >>')" />

HttpUtility.HtmlEncode
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a rework of @Bryan Legend's answer with Linq:

```
public static string EncodeJavaScriptString(string s)
    => string.Concat(s.Select(c => {
        switch (c)
        {
            case '\"': return "\\\"";
            case '\\': return "\\\\";
            case '\b': return "\\b";
            case '\f': return "\\f";
            case '\n': return "\\n";
            case '\r': return "\\r";
            case '\t': return "\\t";
            default: return (c < 32 || c > 127) && !char.IsLetterOrDigit(c) ? $"\\u{(int)c:X04}" : c.ToString();
        }}));
```

[Try it Online!](https://dotnetfiddle.net/PoL4BM)

changelog:

- Remove double quoting wrapping since I do it in the js
- Use expression body
- Use a cleaner switch
- Use Linq
- Add a check for Letter to allow `é`

Comment: It's 5 times slower than Bryan Legend's answer.

Answer (score -1):

Well, for starters you do not need quotes around the keys.

```
{rows:[,]} is valid.

and you could dt.Table.Columns[i].ToString().Replace("\","")
```

But if you want to retain the double quotes, single quote works the same way double quotes do in JS

Otherwise you could do

```
String.Format("{name: \"{0}\"}",Columns[i].ToString().Replace("\",""))
```