# Escape all characters that need to be escaped

Tags: c#, javascript

I am using a modal window in my asp.net application. On clicking a button I do some serverside processing and then use cs.RegisterStartupScript to close the window and return a value to the parent window. To do that I use RegisterStartupScript to run window.close.

Now the problem i am having is that I want to send a return value (a string) to the parent. But since the string is a user entered text that can have any characters, I need to escape all of them. Without that I am unable to send the return value to the parent.

This is my script that causes failure (error message : 
unterminated string constant
DO you want to continue running scripts on this page?)

```
  StringBuilder saveScript = new StringBuilder();
    saveScript.Append("var template = new Object();");
    saveScript.AppendFormat("template.DescriptionPlainText = \"{0}\";",description);
    saveScript.Append("window.returnValue = template;");
    saveScript.Append("window.close();");
    cs.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(myPageType), scriptName, saveScript.ToString(), true);
```

description is a string.

However this succeeds

```
StringBuilder saveScript = new StringBuilder();
saveScript.Append("var template = new Object();");
saveScript.AppendFormat("template.DescriptionPlainText = \"{0}\";","xx");
saveScript.Append("window.returnValue = template;");
saveScript.Append("window.close();");
cs.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(myPageType), scriptName, saveScript.ToString(), true);
```

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "C#" and such. That's what the tags are for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you escape your user input `description` for Javascript use, then it should work fine.

See here: [Escape Quote in C# for javascript consumption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/806944/escape-quote-in-c-sharp-for-javascript-consumption)

Comment: Lone Coder's solution on your link worked for me. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [AntiXss library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/security/aa973814) for encoding text for Html/JavaScript consumption. Check out [older article on AntiXss](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa973813.aspx#anticross_sitescripting_topic4_three) with some more guidance.

```
 AntiXss.JavaScriptEncode("r'\"a&<>dom!");
```