# Javascript function parameter character escape

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I need to pass a variable to a JavaScript function, but I have a little trouble. In the .cs file, I have written:

```
string id = "some'id";
this.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<input type=\"button\" onClick=\"myFunction('"+id+"')\">"));
```

As you can see there is an `'` (single quote) in the id.  Is there any way to work around this issue?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Escape Quote in C# for javascript consumption](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/806944/escape-quote-in-c-sharp-for-javascript-consumption)

Comment: Both strings appear fine to me in Chrome.

Answer (score 2):

Escape `'` with a `\` (backslash). For example,

```
console.log('string with \'');
```

Answer (score 1):

Escape your string for such kind of characters"/","\","'"

example

```
string id = "some/'id";
```

Answer (score 0):

You should escape your string , which would lead to :

```
 id = "some\'id";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function myFunction(someid) {
        someid = someid.replace('#', '\'');
        alert(someid);
    }
</script>
```

in Your code

```
string id = "some'id".Replace("'","#");

this.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<input type=\"button\" value=\"Test\" onclick=\"myFunction('" + id + "');\">"));
```

Hope this will Helps you..