# Unterminated string constant error in asp.net

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

[image]

Got this error while call the function

```
 static public void DisplayAJAXMessage(Control page, string msg)
{
    string myScript = String.Format("alert('{0}');", msg);

    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(page, page.GetType(), "MyScript", myScript, true);
}
```

Calling this function:

```
    string sampledata = "Name                  :zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz<br>Phone         :00000000000000<br>Country               :India";
        string sample = sampledata.Replace("<br>", "\n");


    MsgBox.DisplayAJAXMessage(this, sample);
```

I need to display Name,Phone and Country in next line.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unterminated string constant means you've forgotten to close your string. You can't have an alert that runs over multiple lines. When the script is outputting to the browser, it's actually including the new lines.. not the "\n" like the javascript expects. That means, your alert call is going over multiple lines.. like this:

```
alert('Name                  :zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz
       Phone         :00000000000000
       Country               :India');
```

..which won't work, and will produce the error you're seeing. Try using double backslash to escape the backslash:

```
string sample = sampledata.Replace("<br>", "\\n");
```

Comment: How to set the font size as 14px and font as courier new font for that alert box.

Comment: You can't... Your best option is a custom alert dialog .. perhaps something with jQuery UI. That's a separate subject though..

Comment: how to create custom alert dialog box?

Answer (score 3):

`"\n"` is a newline for C#, i.e. your js contains:

```
something('...blah foo
bar ...');
```

what you *actually* want is a newline in js:

```
something('...blah foo\nbar ...');
```

which you can do with:

```
string sample = sampledata.Replace("<br>", "\\n");
```

or:

```
string sample = sampledata.Replace("<br>", @"\n");
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape/encode your string being consumed by `JavaScript`:

[Escape Quote in C# for javascript consumption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/806944/escape-quote-in-c-sharp-for-javascript-consumption)

Answer (score 0):

Your Unterminated is not in C# is in Javascript generated code.