# Serializing with JavaScriptSerializer properly

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, .net

I'm using JavaScriptSerializer to serialize objects. And I had trouble with it when serializing Exceptions. Or rather when deserializing serialized Exceptions, as it contains new line characters and backslashes for the file paths. (let's save controversies for another time).

I have done a "js encoding" extension method to overcome that problem, very similar to the following one:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2680805/385926

But I know that Asp.Net WebMethods serialize automatically to JSON, and the exceptions are serialized properly with no extra programming.

So how does asp.net deal with those special char cases when serializing to JSON? Is there any class or method to deal with it? Aren't my extension method and that JsEncoding methods redundant for something that already exists in .Net?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

Codes as requested. I have a aspx page that does:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.ContentType = "application/json";
    var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

    try
    {
        // do the file manipulation and registering
        Process();

        Response.Clear();
        Response.Write(serializer.Serialize(new
        {
            d = true
        }));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {   
        Response.Clear();
        Response.Write(serializer.Serialize(new
        {
            Message = ex.Message,
            ExceptionType = ex.GetType().ToString(),
            StackTrace = ex.StackTrace
        }));
    }

}
```

When there is some exception, I can't deserialize with JSON.parse (actually I'm not sure if this is within jQuery or built in the browsers). JSON.parse throws exceptions because there are newline chars (instead of \n strings), and other special chars. For example, it would try to parse the following exception (and it fails):

```
{"Message":"User not authenticated.","ExceptionType":"System.Exception","StackTrace":" at MyWebTest.MySite.Process() in C:\Solutions\MyWebTest\MySite.aspx.cs:line 100
at MyWebTest.MySite.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Solutions\MyWebTest\MySite\.aspx.cs:line 60"}
```

Instead it should return the following (as it is parsed correctly):

```
{"Message":"User not authenticated.","ExceptionType":"System.Exception","StackTrace":" at MyWebTest.MySite.Process() in C:\\\\Solutions\\\\\MyWebTest\\\\MySite.aspx.cs:line 100\\r\\n at MyWebTest.MySite.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\\\\Solutions\\\\MyWebTest\\\\MySite.aspx.cs:line 60"}
```

So I created a extension method that does the replacements. And the code is chaged to:

```
new
{
    Message = ex.Message.JsEncode(),
    ExceptionType = ex.GetType().ToString(),
    StackTrace = ex.StackTrace.JsEncode()
}));
```

Comment: How are new lines and backslashes causing problems? `JavaScriptSerializer` does the necessary escaping for strings. What specific problem are you having?

Comment: Please provide some code with inputs and outputs, without that anyone here is only guessing but also as the above poster said the serializer shouldn't really care about new lines and the rest. I'd say something else is going on.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue with a JSON string containing double quotes.  I ended up escaping it properly with `HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode` after serializing:

```
ApplicationDataJson =
    HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(
        new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(
            applicationData));
```

So to your original code,

```
catch (Exception ex)
{   
    Response.Clear();
    Response.Write(HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(
        serializer.Serialize(new
        {
            Message = ex.Message,
            ExceptionType = ex.GetType().ToString(),
            StackTrace = ex.StackTrace
        }
    )));
}
```