# If filename has single quote C# javascript does not get executed

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I need to pass a URL from C# to javascript. The problem is if the filename has single quote, it does not execute the javascript. When I use HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(fileNameWithoutEx) it does execute javascript but if filename is say "Copy of David's Birth Certificate" then URL gets converted to ?View.aspx?length=60&ext=pdf&file=Copy of David&#39; Birth Certificate.

When View.aspx tries to get the querystring file i.e; filename, it gets set to "Copy of David" and not "Copy of David's Birth Certificate". Because of & it does not get the rest of the querystring.

```
 if (System.IO.File.Exists(fileLocation)) {
            string fileNameWithoutExt = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileLocation);
            string fileExtension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(fileLocation).Replace(".", "");
            string title = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName);
            string url = "View?length=" + 60+ "&ext=" + fileExtension + "&file=" + fileNameWithoutExt;
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "ShowPDF", "$(document).ready(function(){ShowPDFDocument('" + title + "', '" + url + "');});", true);                                      
}
```

How can I send url with single quote to javascript?

What's the best way to handle ' and other special characters?

Comment: I dont know ASP.NET much, but it seems your `HTTPUtility.HtmlEncode()` do the exacte same thing as a PHP function called `Htmlentities()` which in PHP you could replace by `HtmlSpecialChars()` maybe you could find the equivalent of htmlspecialschars in ASP.NET

Comment: `HttpUtility.HtmlEncode` is used for `HTML content` not `URL`.

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/a/8311240/507793 (requires .net 4)

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help!! Highly appreciate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Uri.EscapeDataString(yourLinkHere);`. See [Uri.EscapeDataString on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.escapedatastring.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You're embedding the title and URL within quote-delimited strings in JavaScript, so you need to escape them.

```
title = title.Replace("'","\\'");
url = url.Replace("'","\\'");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try percent codes. I would recommned using `%20` in the place of spaces as well. You can chance the file name itself or the way you route to it in code.

```
urlstring.replace("'", "%27")
```

Try to replace your `'` with `%27` which is the standard percent encode for `'`

Characters with reserved purposes should be replaced to guarantee functionality in all environments. You can view the list and read up on this [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding).

Comment: This will work for url but it will not display title properly.  It'll show `%27` to the user.

Comment: @Samuel Neff Very true, I believe I understand his issue and tried to address his quesiton about handling special characters. My answer will work but as you said it will present a different URL value to the user. Correct me if I am misunderstanding him.

Comment: your answer will work, but so would `title = 'some random title``.  No more error, but not the right content either.