# Special character replacement from code of the apostrophe in a file name path

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, silverlight

The problem I'm having is in regards to a file that is being generated on the server and the .NET code is invoking a Javascript method to download a file to the client, but it fails if the file name has an apostrophe (').

So for example:

If the `ExportExcelFileName = "C:\HereIsMyFile.xls"` it works fine.
However, if the
 `ExportExcelFileName = "C:\Here'sMyFile.xls"`

it throws a failure to evaluate exception.

I tried adding `[.Replace("'", "\\'")]` and `[.Replace("'", "%27")]` but no luck...

```
string script = string.Format("DownLoadFile('{0}')", e.Result.ExportExcelFileName).Replace('\\', '/');
HtmlPage.Window.Eval(script);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out:

when I tried this:

```
string script = string.Format("DownLoadFile('{0}')", e.Result.ExportExcelFileName).Replace('\\', '/').Replace("'", "\\'");
HtmlPage.Window.Eval(script);
```

It was also replacing the single quotes in the javascript command of DownloadFile('{0}').

So I simply did the replacement first like so:

```
var escapedFileName = ((e.Result.ExportExcelFileName).Replace('\\', '/')).Replace("'", "\\'");
string script = string.Format("DownLoadFile('{0}')", escapedFileName);
HtmlPage.Window.Eval(script);
```

Answer (score 0):

Would a simple method like this work?

```
private static string quoteReplace(string psString)
{
    return psString.Replace("'", "");
}
```

Comment: why would [after replacing a single (') with ('')] "C:\Here''sMyFile.xls" work? Is this something specific to Javascript?

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. It should have just been replacing it with nothing

Answer (score 0):

Try using URI escaping for the file name:

`Uri.EscapeDataString(filePathHere);`. See [Uri.EscapeDataString on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.escapedatastring.aspx).

Also see: [If filename has single quote C# javascript does not get executed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18411046/if-filename-has-single-quote-c-sharp-javascript-does-not-get-executed)