# Store values in C# and populate in Javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I am working in asp.net 1.1 site.

My requirement is : On post back I have some data, which I want to store in some variable. And in javascript i want to add those info to a drop down list.

Ex :

The data coming from post back call is :

```
Text        Value
One             1
two             2
three           3
```

I want to store them in some variable and assign them to a drop down list in JAVASCRIPT based on a condidtion.

The code I am using to keep the value in C# is:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append("<script>");
sb.Append("var test = [];");
for(int i=0; i < Engine.Length; i++)
{
    sb.Append("var obj = {text:" + Engine[i][0] + ","  + "value:" + Engine[i][1] +"};");
    sb.Append("test.push(obj);");
}
sb.Append("</" + "script>");

this.RegisterStartupScript("ownHtml", sb.ToString());
```

And adding the value to drop down list in JAVASCRIPT as:

```
for (var count = 0; count < test.length; count++)
{
    dlEngine.options[count] = new Option(test[count].text, test[count].value);
}
```

But it is not working.

Comment: What error do you get? And why are you declaring obj multiple times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides @i100 's answer, also need to modify the server side code, you've missed the quotes.

```
sb.Append("var obj = {text:'" + Engine[i][0] + "',"  + "value:" + Engine[i][1] +"};");
```

Comment: Plus don't forget to escape properly otherwise this is an injection attack - what happens if (somehow) one of your values contained quotes? Imagine this if the value was `Something'};alert('security fail');//`... You'd get `var obj = {text:'Something'};alert('security fail');//...` See [the answers here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/806944/156755) for some solutions

Answer (score 0):

instead of 
for (var count = 0; count < test.length; count++)

```
{
    dlEngine.options[count] = new Option(test[count].text, test[count].value);
}
```

use something like

```
for (var count = 0; count < test.length; count++){
    var opt = document.createElement('option');
    opt.value = test[count].value;
    opt.innerHTML = test[count].text;
    dlEngine.appendChild(opt);
}
```