# Is there a built in function for escaping quotes

Tags: c#, javascript

My signup page at http://nettpals.in/pages/signup, because, I'm creating an array of user names.

One users has kept his name as john'orielly, which is causing the array to break.

Like this:

```
var array=['joe','jook','john'orielly'];
```

Is there any way to escape these `'` single quotes?

Code to populate the array:

```
public static string StringTokenizr(this List<string> list, NpStringTokenizrType type, string splitter = ",")
        {
            string s = null;
            if (list.Count == 0) return null;
            for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
            {
                if (type == NpStringTokenizrType.IntegerLike)
                    s += list[i] + splitter;
                else s += "'" + list[i] + "'" + splitter;

            }
            return s.RemoveLast();// removes last comma
        }
```

Comment: That looks like JavaScript not C#...?

Comment: yeah, but the value is created in c#

Comment: How do you populate the array (Code)?

Comment: I'll update my question

Comment: replace `'` with `&quot;`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Escape Quote in C# for javascript consumption](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/806944/escape-quote-in-c-sharp-for-javascript-consumption)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way, assuming the names are stored in a generic list:

```
var array=[<%=string.Join(",  ", arrNames.ConvertAll(name => string.Format("'{0}'", name.Replace("'", "\\'"))))%>];
```

Saw your edit just now so the above is one liner for the `StringTokenizr` you have.

Answer (score 0):

You could try replacing the single quote `'` with the html equivalent `&quot;` this would then render on the page correctly and not break your array